# Is there a way to have vim start line numbering at 0?

Tags: vim

I have added the `set nu` to my vimrc file, and I like it, but I would like to have vim start with line number 0 (it's to match the samples from a book I am using to learn C++).

I saw a suggestion to change `set nu` to `set rnu`, and at first it looked good, until I moved downward, and the 0 moved with my cursor. I understand what's going on here - it's displaying a 0 for my current position, and the lines above and below are renumbered relative to where 0 is. While cool, this is not what I want.

Thanks in advance!

Shane

Comment: I guess you can't...? It is just built deeply into Vim, so all the internal functions and so on depend on this. To me it sounds like asking C++ to begin the index with 1 instead.

Comment: Does this plugin help you? https://github.com/rickhowe/partialnumber.vim

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible without patching the source.

Note that, in Vim, line numbers can be used in many more ways than in "regular" editors so changing how the line numbers are displayed will have a non-negligible impact in other areas. This doesn't seem like a very good idea.